# AngularJS httpInterceptor set Date Header Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Below code is my $http Interceptor Factory. In this code, I have set date header value to current date at **config.headers.Date** but it is showing null in Asp.Net WebApi Request Header Class. How can I set Date Header value to get Local DateTime value from client.

```
'use strict';
define(['appconfig'], function (app) {

  app.factory('authInterceptorFactory', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {

    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {

      config.headers = config.headers || {};

      // set date
      config.headers.Date = new Date().toUTCString();

      // set authorization
      var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
      if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
      }

      return config;
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
  }]);
});
```

This is my WebApi Controller.But ** ApiService.ClientDate ** always return server date due to the value of request.Headers.Date is returning null.Please advice how should I send the client datetime to access from server.

```
public class AuthorizeController : ApiController
{
  private ConnectionProvider cp;

  protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
  {
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
      var request = controllerContext.Request;

      // get connection name from claims
      ClaimsPrincipal principal = request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
      var Site = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "site").Single().Value;

      // create db connection
      cp = new ConnectionProvider(Site);
      ApiService.dbConnection = cp.GetDbConnection();

      // create db context
      ApiService.dbContext = new Models.WarenetModel(Site);

      ApiService.UserId = User.Identity.Name;    // set userId
      ApiService.HostName = request.Headers.Host;    // set hostname
      ApiService.ClientDate = request.Headers.Date.HasValue ? request.Headers.Date.Value.LocalDateTime : DateTime.Now;     // set client date
    }
  }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing) {
      if (cp != null) cp.Dispose();
      if (ApiService.dbContext != null) ApiService.dbContext.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use angular tag for angularJs. Thank you.

Comment: Use Chrome devtools or alike to find out, if the header gets send by the client. Use curl or alike to verify if the header gets honored by the server. This doesn't solve anything, but it makes you know, what part is wrong, effectively halving the problem. +++ The `Date` header gets special treatment. Try the same with a  custom header. +++ Is CORS in use?